# How to get a correctly-chained stack trace for exceptions thrown when handling other exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

Suppose I am handling `FooException` and `BarException` occurs. Let's assume they are both unchecked exceptions.

What I want to see in the stacktrace is:

```
com.bar.BarException: Bar Message
    at com.baz.BazCode(BazCode.java:123)
    ...
Caused by: com.foo.FooException: Foo Message
    at com.baz.BazCode(BazCode.java:321)
    ....
Caused by: ...
```

However, by default, all record of `FooException` will be erased from the stacktrace. For example:

```
// In a class written by me
/**
  * ...
  * @throws FooException if foo happens
  * @throws BarException if bar happens
  */
public void upperFrame() {
    try {
        foo.doSomething();
    } catch (FooException foo) {
        bar.doSomethingElse();
    }
}

// In class Bar (not written by me)
public void doSomethingElse() {
    if (someConditionWhichHappensToBeTrueInThisScenario()) {
        throw new BarException("Hello Bar World"); // At this point, FooException gets erased from the stack trace
    }
}
```

If `BarException` has a `(message, cause)` constructor then I can follow a rather crude kind of "manual cloning" process to achieve my goal:

```
try {
    foo.doSomething();
} catch (FooException foo) {
    try {
        bar.doSomethingElse();
    } catch (BarException bar) {
        BarException bar2 = new BarException(bar.getMessage(), foo);
        bar2.setStackTrace(bar.getStackTrace());
        throw bar2;
    }
}
```

However, if `BarException` does not have such a constructor (for example `ClassCastException`) then I am reduced to doing things like this:

```
try {
    foo.doSomething();
} catch (FooException foo) {
    try {
        bar.doSomethingElse();
    } catch (BarException bar) {
        RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException("com.bar.BarException: " + bar.getMessage(), foo);
        e.setStackTrace(bar.getStackTrace());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This is dangerous because `e` has the wrong type and so may not be correctly handled by higher frames.

Is there a "best-practice" way to handle this situation?

Comment: Is the stacktrace of `FooException` lost when creating a `BarException` with a Foo cause? Or could you do something like `bar.getCause().getStackTrace()`?

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg I've edited my question to show how `FooException` gets lost. It's not related to any creation of an exception with a cause, it's an exception thrown by the method `doSomethingElse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`Throwable#initCause(Throwable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)) method:

```java
bar.initCause(foo);
```

Comment: Good point (I didn't notice this method as I only looked for a `setCause` method)....as long as `BarException` doesn't already define a cause. However, I've yet to find any exception class (at least within the java specification) which defines a cause yet lacks a `(message, cause)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you pass the original exception to the new one as an argument, it creates the "caused by" chain and the stack trace is preserved. Your use cases seem a bit strange. To me, the exception when recovering or handling the error with more than some logging is another error and not really "caused by" the other error. I would just log the "foo" and throw the "bar".

In some cases I guess your way could make sense. To do this, you could pass the "foo" on as doSomethingElse(foo) and throw new BarException(foo) when something goes wrong handling this. Pretty much all standard exceptions support this constructor, and if you need to make your own just create a constructor that delegates to these.

I personally would not use them the way you seem to though. I use them to throw a different type of exception than the one I caught, if I want a different type for some reason. For example, to translate to exceptions of specific type to my application, or to translate checked to unchecked in cases where that makes sense. In such cases it is still good to keep the original exception and the full "caused by.." trace..

Comment: "I would just log the foo and throw the bar": Logging exceptions and then discarding them is not good practice. What if another library depended on your code and was using a non-standard logger (such as JMS logging)? "Pretty much all standard exceptions support this constructor" they don't, `ClassCastException` is just one example

Comment: "I personally would not use them the way you seem to though. I use them to throw a different type of exception to the one I caught" - what gives you the impression that this is not what I am trying to do? Exceptions such as `ClassCastException` can still occur when trying to throw a different type of exception to the one I caught

Comment: "To do this, you could pass the foo on as doSomethingElse(foo)" - As I stated in my question, doSomethingElse is not in a class written by me. And it doesn't support passing an exception as an argument.

Comment: Do you often find yourself needing to throw a ClassCastException with another exception as a cause? Or do you actually have a realistic example? I was not expecting you to ignore exceptions when you log them, just that if there is an issue getting all the data copied and you need another type, you can just log it and throw what you can. The stacktrace is most likely for human consumption anyway, so you can find it in the log just as well. In your example with "bar2" you can just leave out the try-catch since you want to throw the exact same thing.

Comment: And you should know what is the correct type for your "higher frame" and just manage that. Should not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I want to throw an exception of the same **type**, but with a different cause. And yes, I do need to throw a `ClassCastException` with another exception as the cause, otherwise that exception will get erased from the stack trace.